Trackpad not working after waking up from sleep (weird behaviour)
The trackpad on my Dell Inspiron laptop stops working after it goes to sleep when I close the lid. If I put the laptop to sleep from software or from the power button, the trackpad works after waking up. The weird behaviour is that if the trackpad is not working after closing the lid, I can make it work by putting the laptop to sleep from the power button. The laptop is set to [deep] sleep mode.
This are the things I have tried:

The usual answer is to try stopping and starting it with modprobe. Not working.
Tried to disable and enable it with xinput disable/enable. Not working.
I have checked that actually [deep] sleep mode is triggered in both cases, and it is.
The trackpad is not listed on xinput after closing the lid, it appears again after power-button sleep.
If I change the sleep mode to s2idle then the trackback keeps working, but this is not a solution as I want to save most of the battery as possible.

I thought this was a hardware issue, but then why does the trackpad comes back to life after sleep from the power button?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 6.5 (I'm not on the laptop so I don't remember the details, but I will add them if required).
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I have the same kind of issues with a Dell Precision under 22.04.
I don't have a way to prevent the issue but this is my workaround : activate/desactivate the touchpad from the command line using xinput for example with this script (from Medium).
#!/bin/bash

# Try to auto-detect touchpad ID if not set
if [ -z "$DEVICE" ]; then
    DEVICE=$(xinput list | grep -i 'touchpad' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')
fi

# Check if DEVICE is still empty
if [ -z "$DEVICE" ]; then
    echo "Unable to detect touchpad device. Please set DEVICE manually."
    exit 1
fi

STATUS=$(xinput list-props $DEVICE | grep "Device Enabled" | awk '{print $4}')

if [ "$STATUS" == "1" ]; then
    echo "Disabling"
    xinput disable $DEVICE
else
    echo "Enabling"
    xinput enable $DEVICE
fi

